# Dynamic function to flatten a nested XML payload into rows and columns

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, plsql, payload

Regardless of the xml structure, it could be for example parent and child or it could be parent, child, grandchild and so on, but I want to be able to parse a payload and have a function convert and flatten any XML file into rows and columns within a table.

The idea is to create a function and then call this using SQL query. Ideally i would create a object and table and then pipeline the results to a temporary table.

I've searched high and low and haven't found anything generic as yet for Oracle. The example I have found are where a function has been built to accomodate a specific xml, bu this function has to be clever enough to dynamically create the columns and rows using some sort of loop though the nested elements I would presume.

Comment: What is the end goal - just to get the data into a temporary table? How will anything know how to query and handle data from that if the structure isn't known? Also how will you handle/maintain relationships between the parent/child levels in a single flat table - lots of duplication?

Comment: Yes I agree there will be a lot of duplication but the idea is to have a generic structure that handles lots of different xml payloads without having to build a function for each one. The idea is to first run the function with payload as input variable and the table is returned. I have over 200 xml payloads that I want a simple function to handle. The inefficiency of the data returned is low price to pay for the flexibility I need.

Comment: A database is a 2 dimensional object with rows and columns.   XML can have many layers of descendants as well as attributes and innertext.  I have flattened many xml, but there isn't a good technique that is generic to flatten a multi-layer xml into only two dimensions.

Comment: Oracle doesn't allow dynamic result structure in static SQL. SQL processing stages are: parse (syntax and semantic checks) -> build execution plan -> **bind variables** (this is a step where actual data is passed to the executor) -> execute. Result set structure is known at the parsing stage, so it cannot be based on any data. Just by design. Also note that PL/SQL is also statically typed and it cannot handle arbitrary structures also (without abstract types like sys.Anydata, which in any way should be consumed by static types or external program).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I understand the nature of 2d however the nature of nested tags is that everything can be pulled back to create a master record, it's always a tree and every tree has a root so to render this to the root should be possible

Comment: @astentx not sure I fully understand your point, in Linux for example there is a way to search directories recursively from a parent directory and copy these files into a single directory, this would be no different in my mind and is fairly analogous, we are simply using a search for nested tags and returning the  aggregated subset of data back to the master using a loop until such time as we get to the last nested tag and once the last record is processed we exit and so continue to the next child record until we are done, so in that sense it should be able to handle arbitrary structures.

Comment: There's no any code or data in your question to discuss. Please update the question with the data and desired result to be able to provide you a solution. What I was talking about is result set structure (columns): it is fixed for a given query and cannot be chaged based on any data.

Answer (score 0):

To do what you want you need to use a function "RETURN ANYDATASET PIPELINED USING package_name", passing the XML and the required parameters: name of the root node, name the row node, name of the "children" node, name of if "id" and names of the other columns.

In the package you will need to implement the ODCI interface: ODCITableDescribe, ODCITablePrepare, ODCITableStart, ODCITableFetch, ODCITableClose.

The ODCITableDescribe is where you will have to generate dynamically the query based on the parameters, and then calling DBMS_SQL.PARSE, DBMS_SQL.DESCRIBE_COLUMNS2. You will have to invent your own way to meta-describe the column types of the result (NUMBER, DATE, ...), if not they will all be textual. You will need to build the ANYDATA meta description with ANYTYPE.BEGINCREATE/ENDCREATE for both the row type (DBMS_TYPES.TYPECODE_OBJECT) and the ANYDATASET (DBMS_TYPES.typecode_table).

You can use the following example as source to inspire to have a "template" of the query to generate (without the CTE of course, just here to test and understand what it does):

```
with data(xml) as (
    select xmltype(q'{<rows>
    <row>
        <id>1</id>
        <name>A</name>
        <children>
            <row>
                <id>11</id>
                <name>A1</name>
                <children>
                    <row>
                        <id>111</id>
                        <name>A11</name>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <id>112</id>
                        <children>
                            <row>
                                <id>1121</id>
                                <name>A121</name>
                            </row>
                        </children>
                    </row>
                    <row>
                        <id>113</id>
                    </row>
                </children>
            </row>
        </children>
    </row>
    <row>
        <id>2</id>
        <children>
            <row>
                <id>21</id>
                <name>B1</name>
            </row>
        </children>
    </row>
</rows>}') as xml from dual
)
-- root nodes only
select t.id, t.name, null as parent_id
from data d,
xmltable(
        -- here you should build the path of first level rows bases on you parameters
        '/rows/row' passing d.xml
        columns
            -- the column identifying the rows
            id path 'id',
            -- one path per "other" columns...
            name path 'name'
    ) t
union all 
-- all children nodes
select t.id, t.name, t.parent_id 
from data d,
xmltable(
        -- you will need to have one attribute per "other" column
        -- and build dynamically the path of the children rows
        'for $c in //row/children/row 
            return <child id="{$c/id}" name="{$c/name}" parent_id="{$c/../../id}">{$c}</child>' passing d.xml
        columns
            -- the id column
            id path '@id',
            -- one path per "other" columns...
            name path '@name',
            -- plus the "parent" id
            parent_id path '@parent_id'
    ) t
;
```